# Curly Curly on ggplot label

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I am using curly curly using in labs in ggplot, it doesn't seem to work, how to use the label on the labs in ggplot in Try #2. For Try#3 I want to pass all numeric variable through purr in the function.

## TRY #1 - This works

```
library(tidyverse)

myplot <- function(df,col) {
  df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x={{col}}))+
  geom_histogram()+
   # labs(title=paste0("Histogram for ",{{col}}))+
    theme_classic()
}

myplot(iris,Sepal.Length)
```

## TRY #2 - This doesnt work

```
myplot <- function(df,col) {
  df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x={{col}}))+
  geom_histogram()+
   labs(title=paste0("Histogram for ",{{col}}))+
    theme_classic()
}

myplot(iris,Sepal.Length)
```

## TRY #3 -  This doesnt work either

```
myplot <- function(df,col) {
  df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x={{col}}))+
  geom_histogram()+
  theme_classic()
}

iris[,-5] %>% 
  map(myplot)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are ok passing column names as strings.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

myplot <- function(df,col) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=.data[[col]]))+
    geom_histogram()+
    labs(title=paste0("Histogram for ",col))+
    theme_classic()
}

list_plot <- map(names(iris)[-5], ~myplot(iris, .))
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect, any solution to catch if not passing as a string and catching via {{ in ggplot aesthethics

Comment: You can pass the variables as symbols to the same function. `list_plot1 <- map(syms(names(iris)[-5]), ~myplot(iris, .))`. I am not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can do old-school `deparse(substitute(...))` to capture the symbol as text.

```r
library(tidyverse)

myplot <- function(df,col) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x={{col}}))+
    geom_histogram()+
    labs(title=paste0("Histogram for ", deparse(substitute(col))))+
    theme_classic()
}

myplot(iris,Sepal.Length)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, anything on how to pass all numeric columns via map function rather than separately calling this function for all numeric columns

Comment: Nope, I'm not fluent in purrr

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to make use of `rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(col))`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

myplot <- function(df, col) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x={{col}}))+
    geom_histogram()+
    labs(title=paste0("Histogram for ", rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(col)))) +
    theme_classic()
}

myplot(iris,Sepal.Length)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

If you want to loop over multiple columns one option would be to rewrite your function slightly to make use of the `.data` pronoun from `rlang` and to loop over the column names:

```r
myplot2 <- function(df, col) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = .data[[col]]))+
    geom_histogram()+
    labs(title=paste0("Histogram for ", col)) +
    theme_classic()
}

p <- purrr::map(names(iris[,-5]), myplot2, df = iris)

p[[2]]
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Comment: Curious how does col work here in labs but not below 
myplot2 <- function(df, col) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = {{col}}))+
    geom_histogram()+
    labs(title=paste0("Histogram for ", col)) +
    theme_classic()
}

myplot2(iris,Sepal.Length)

Comment: Also how do I interpret the order of the argument passing to the function via map 
df is iris, does names(iris[-5]) gets passed as col to myplot?

Comment: Hm. For your first question. `col` is neither a character nor an object in your environment. That's why your code does not work. It only exists inside the dataframe. That's what `{{` is doing. It tells R to look for col inside your df. However, this does not work in all places. For more on this I would suggest to have a look at e.g. https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/multiple.html. For your second question. map(names(iris[-5]), ...). is in some sense doing `for (col in names(iris[-5]))`, i.e. it loops over the column names an passes them one for one to your function.